# Inserting images in ShareLaTeX

Tags: graphics, sharelatex

I have no idea how to correctly define my graphics path on [ShareLaTeX](http://sharelatex.com). In a Linux terminal my folder location would look like: `\home\Libraries\Documents\paperimages`

I'm sorry if this is asked on the usual, but I cannot find any real substantial help online.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

For images in folder `images`, you use

```
\graphicspath{{images/}}
```

More folders require separate braced groups like above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official guide on inserting images in ShareLaTeX: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Inserting_Images

In particular, this is how you set the path:

```
%Path in Windows format:
\graphicspath{ {c:/user/images/} }

%Path in Unix-like (Linux, OsX) format
\graphicspath{ {/home/user/images/} }
```